# What makes glBufferSubData slow on big buffer?

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo

I've noticed that updating a small amount of vertices in VBO goes very slow as buffer size grows. For example, when I update, say, 2 verts in a 512*512 buffer is much slower then when I update the whole 256*256 buffer despite the amounts of data updated are quite opposite. **Is this a normal behavior for glBufferSubData?**

This is how I allocate the buffer:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(uiMapView::vertex)*(size + 1)*(size + 1), m_verts, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

This is how I update it:

```
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(uiMapView::vertex)*iMinId, sizeof(uiMapView::vertex)*(iMaxId-iMinId), (&m_verts[iMinId]));
```

Comment: This question is unanswerable unless much more details are given. The buffer update performance will be heavily influenced by the access pattern on the buffer, the update frequency, and of course the specific implementation. The [free chapter on Asynchronous Buffer Transfers from the OpenGL Insights book](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~pcozzi/OpenGLInsights/OpenGLInsights-AsynchronousBufferTransfers.pdf) might explain some of the issues you have to deal with.

Comment: @derhass, thanks for a useful link, but that wasn't really an issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I made some more research on my solution and found out that VBO updating wasn't really a bottleneck. The reason of slowing my program down was an amount of calculations made with the data, wich obviously made the biggest impact.

So, actually, the right anser is: **no, this is not a normal behaviour for glBufferSubData**. The buffer size doesn't make *such a great* impact on glBufferSubData performance.